# Postgresql and old persistant data

Tags: postgresql

Has anyone had a problem with old persistent data hanging around using PostgreSQL. I recently ran a report and got two separate outcomes. Six records were missing from the second time I ran the report.

Comment: No PostgreSQL is completely bug free.  Take a look for the problem between the keyboard and the chair.

Comment: @DarrylMiles Hah! Nothing is ever bug free, and there's a slow-but-steady trickle of reports to the mailing list. That said, they're usually either packaging/installer issues or corner cases affecting newer features. Bugs in the basic data handling are almost, but not totally, unheard of.

Comment: @user1681134 Your question lacks enough detail for anybody to usefully answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost completely certain that the problem is in your code or how you are using PostgreSQL. You haven't given anywhere near enough information for anybody to explain that - not even your PostgreSQL version!

Bugs that affect the core MVCC design of transactional isolation and visibility are reported to the mailing list, but only vanishingly rarely, and they've tended to be in funky corner cases that would not usually be encountered.

The only times I've seen data come back from the dead are when:

- The user has been running with `fsync=off` or on storage that lies about fsync, and they've crashed & restarted the machine after a `DELETE`. They had some `DELETE`d data back, as well as some fun corrupt tables and indexes. Setting `fsync=off` basically tells PostgreSQL "make it faster, I don't care if you destroy all my data", so this was a perfectly valid outcome.
- Someone creates an index on a function marked `IMMUTABLE` that isn't really immutable at all. This usually just produces wrong results, but with 9.2's covering indexes I suspect it's possible it could appear to bring data back from the dead too.

So, honestly, it's something you're doing wrong. Try posting a new question with a *lot* more detail:

- Pg version
- How you're running the reports
- DDL
- SQL
- What the database workload is like
- What else was going on at the same time
- What other clients there are

... etc, and maybe someone can help.